# Css - Is it possible to make an element move when screen being resized in order to make it fit the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the link for the code - [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pt6uw53/)

and here's the code -

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>


    <style>
        .can_con {
            border: 1px solid #b6ff00;
            position: absolute;
            top: 25px;
            left: 600px;

        }

        li {
            font-size: 60px;

        }         

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
        <li>Some Text 1</li>
        <li>Some Text 2</li>
        <li>Some Text 3</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="can_con">
        <canvas id="#myCan" width="600" height="200" style="border:1px solid #f00;"></canvas>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Now what I would like to know is if there's a way to make the canvas element not disappear when the screen been zoomed in.

I mean that the current state is that the canvas element  going to the right side of the screen and I would like to avoid this.

So thanks for any kind of help

Comment: What do you mean by 'being zoomed' and where would you want it to go? Surely nothing 'disappears' as such but is just off-screen when the viewport is too narrow for it all to fit. If the `ul` and `.can_con` were displayed inline it would wrap underneath when the browser was narrow. EG: http://jsfiddle.net/7pt6uw53/2/ Perhaps this is what you mean.

Comment: i mean that when i"m zooming in with the browser - meaning other resolution - the part of the canvas is simply out of the screen. and i want the canvas position next to the ul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `float` and `box-sizing`

```
.can_con {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.can_con canvas{
    width:100%;
    display:block
}
ul {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
li {
    font-size: 60px;  
}
```

and remove `width` and `height` from the `<canvas>`tag

```
<canvas id="#myCan" style="border:1px solid #f00;"></canvas>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7pt6uw53/4/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **px** use **em** or **%** to make your layout responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `canvas` be moved bellow the `<ul>` if you put both of them in a container which is floated left if there is not enough space for both of them.

### HTML:

```
 <div class='col'>    
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
        <div class="can_con">
            <canvas ...></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS:

```
.col{
    float:left;
}
.col:last-of-type:after{
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7pt6uw53/5/